# How to highlight the portion matched with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to highlight (with red) the error portion of the input (thus the user can easily find out where and what the error is) and matching the error portion with regex.

I tried something like the following: (say I am accepting letters but not digits)

```
$("#myInputId")
    .filter(function() {
        return this.value.match(/[\d]/);
    })
    .addClass("error")
```

But the above code is highlighting the whole input, but not only the error portion.

I just put the following image to make what I say is more clear:

[image]

**NOTE**: I am trying achieve this without adding any jQuery plugins for highlighting texts.

Comment: So the text you want to highlight is in a text input field (`<input type="text" />`)?

Comment: Of course yes, in my example the texts "James1234", "James123Robert" are in the input fields (sorry, my image is not perfect enough to show this)

Answer (score 3):

The filter function returns true because what is in `this.value` matches the required regex. Thus the whole element `#myInputId` is ok. And to this element you apply the `error` class.

You need to apply the class only to the relevant portion. What you should probably do, is replace the found string **within** the `#myInputId` with the same string only enclosed in an error span.

This:

```
<div id="myInputId">James1234</div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div id="myInputId">James<span class="error">1234</span></div>
```

You can achieve this by using the found string, like this:

```
var newStr = wholeStr.replace(foundStr, '<span class="error">'+foundStr+'</span>');
```

Comment: If I change the user input, bad things happen when user submits the input?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: If the user input is changed, a counter action must be performed on submission of the form (double work)

Comment: Well sure, every time a user submits the text you should find the part that matches the pattern and replace it adding the tags. Now if you want to do it **inside** an input field that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you are adding the class "error" to the element which has all the text "James1234" in it.

At the moment I think something like this is happening

```
<p class="error">
    james1234
</p>
```

if it was free text and you did text replace and changed the html to something like this

```
<p>
    james<span class="error"/>1234<span/>
</p>
```

so to achieve this I think you would need to do something like this

```
    var searchterm = '1234'
    value.replace(searchTerm, "<span class='error'/>" + searchterm + "<span/>");
```

Comment: If I change the user input, bad things happen when user submits the input?

Comment: If you are trying to highlight the errors in an input field then you could try these things 1) add a label next to the input field showing the bad text 2) when a user hits submit do a string replace on the <span class="error"> and strip it out on the way back to the server